# How can I tell if a Perl module is actually used in my program?

Tags: perl

I have been on a "cleaning spree" lately at work, doing a lot of touch-up stuff that should have been done awhile ago. One thing I have been doing is deleted modules that were imported into files and never used, or they were used at one point but not anymore. To do this I have just been deleting an import and running the program's test file. Which gets *really, really* tedious.

Is there any programmatic way of doing this? Short of me writing a program myself to do it.

Comment: I've attempted similar cleaning before, and there isn't any easy way to do it if coders rely on an imported module's default `@EXPORT`.  I try to always encourage people to use an explicit `use Module qw(list);` format since it makes code more self-documenting, but also because it makes this type of cleanup a lot easier.

Comment: @Miller, yes that is definitely part of the problem. Sometimes, I just can't tell where a function is from.

Comment: Perhaps you can wrap each function in all loaded modules automatically and print the module name in the wrapper

Comment: I do this in a quite brutal manner. I remove the module declarations and see whether my program will run without them. Of course, if a module is rarely used, your program may run, but crash on those occasions when it is used. You could also look for all `->` strings and track the method calls and the object creations. Other than that, there's no easy way to find whether or not a module is used since they're always loaded when declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, you can't.

Longer possibly more useful answer, you won't find a general purpose tool that will tell you with 100% certainty whether the module you're purging will actually be used. But you may be able to build a special purpose tool to help you with the manual search that you're currently doing on your codebase. Maybe try a wrapper around your test suite that removes the use statements for you and ignores any error messages except messages that say `Undefined subroutine &__PACKAGE__::foo` and other messages that occur when accessing missing features of any module. The wrapper could then automatically perform a dumb source scan on the codebase of the module being purged to see if the missing subroutine `foo` (or other feature) might be defined in the unwanted module.

You can supplement this with Devel::Cover to determine which parts of your code don't have tests so you can manually inspect those areas and maybe get insight into whether they are using code from the module you're trying to purge.

Due to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) you can't statically determine whether any program, of sufficient complexity, will exit or not. This applies to your problem because the "last" instruction of your program might be the one that uses the module you're purging. And since it is impossible to determine what the last instruction is, or if it will ever be executed, it is impossible to statically determine if that module will be used. Further, in a dynamic language, which can extend the program during it's run, analysis of the source or even the post-compile symbol tables would only tell you what was calling the unwanted module just before run-time (whatever that means).

Because of this you won't find a general purpose tool that works for all programs. However, if you are positive that your code doesn't use certain run-time features of Perl you might be able to write a tool suited to your program that can determine if code from the module you're purging will actually be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You might create alternative versions of the modules in question, which have only an AUTOLOAD method (and import, see comment) in it. Make this AUTOLOAD method croak on use. Put this module first into the include path.

You might refine this method by making AUTOLOAD only log the usage and then load the real module and forward the original function call. You could also have a subroutine first in @INC which creates the fake module on the fly if necessary.

Of course you need a good test coverage to detect even rare uses.

This concept is definitely not perfect, but it might work with lots of modules and simplify the testing.

Comment: does loading imply usage?

Comment: Ok, maybe you should have not only the AUTOLOAD method, but also the import method defined (and maybe add dummy functions for everything the user tries to import), so that it does not complain on use already.

Comment: This really isn't any better than just removing the `use` statement and then testing the code to see if it breaks.  It's fortunate that he actually has test suites for some of his modules, as that's not always the case.  No matter what, he's going to have to attempt to test the code as thoroughly as possible.  It would just be nice if there was an easy way to assess risk.

Comment: This solution isn't really feasible since it is across our entire codebase, a good thought though.